# should we invent a new type of numbers to solve this?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

in the beginning humans tried to solve equations such as 2+x=0 and they invented negative numbers for that purpose, then things like x²=-1 to invent imaginary numbers, but equation like x²+x⁴=0 have no solution? so should humans again invent a new type of numbers?

Comment: Surely $x=0$ is a solution to $x^{2}+x^{4}=0$? With $x\in\mathbb{R}$. Have a look at [Algebraic Closure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_closure)

Comment: It has solutions in $\mathbb{C}$. Let $x^2=u$. Alternatively, write $x^4+x^2=x^2(x^2+1)=x\cdot x \cdot(x-i)\cdot(x+i)=0$

Comment: i mean could there be equations that humans dont know the solution to yet and they have to invent a new type of numbers to do that?

Comment: You can solve all real equations in $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: $$0=x^2+x^4=x^2(x^2+1)\iff x=0\;\;or\;\;x^2=-1\iff x=\sqrt{-1}$$and the complex numbers $\;\Bbb C\;$ solve the last equation.

Comment: so we humans discovered all types of numbers?

Comment: Yes, we are really powerful. Don't you think so?

Comment: @LorieKirchner What is your definition of "number"?

Comment: Bill's question's on the money: what do *you*, @LorieKirchner, understand by "number" ?

Comment: Also: this is not how things work in real life. Nobody cared to solve $x^2=-1$ back in the day. The historical reason was a weird property of [Cardano's formula](http://usf.usfca.edu/vca/PDF/vca-bombelli.pdf). The $x^2=-1$ thing is a fairytale.

Comment: @LorieKirchner. Just for curiosity, I suggest you have a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypercomplex_number. Happy New Year !

Comment: See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Number_system#Classification_of_numbers) a probably nonextensive list of commonly used numbers in mathematics.

Comment: @LorieKirchner. Humans discovered all types of numbers required for today problems. I am sure that other numbers will appear to solve problems we do not know they exist TODAY.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [fundamental theorem of algebra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_algebra) tells you that every polynomial equation can be (completely) solved in $\mathbb{C}$.

By the way:
$$x^2+x^4 = x^2(x+i)(x-i)$$
and thus $x^2+x^4=0$ is solved by $x=0,-i,i$.

As for having to "invent new types of numbers", you can do that. If you are interested in the subject, I would advise you to take a look at the subject of [field extensions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_extension).

Answer (score 0):

To offer a softer answer than Daniel's:

I invented a new (so far as I know) kind of number just the other day. They have horrible properties and no application that I can see. And using known model-theoretic tricks I could keep making more ugly number systems (especially if I don't even require them to be rings or some such).

The set-theoretic universe is likely brimming with things we could call "number systems", that's not really the question. The question is whether there are any of these that solve as many problems as $\mathbb{C}$ does, or which aren't most easily thought of as a construction on an existing number system (e.g. the hyperreals).

Further, many of our common number systems have notable universal properties that make them especially useful, the way $\mathbb{N}$ is a NNO and the free monoid on one generator, and $\mathbb{Z}$ is the free group on one generator and a separator in the category of groups. These sorts of properties make our common number systems very natural and very powerful to single out.